# loop bash script with subfolders

Tags: bash, loops

I am looping through multiple input files for two programs: `bamtofastq-1.3.2` and `cellranger count` The output from `bamtofastq-1.3.2` makes a folder ($FILE.folder) and a subfolder in which the files I need for the `cellranger count` are stored. I am linking to this folder using wildcard. However, the path to the files are not recognised. Any idea if the wildcards are wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash
mapfile -s 1 -t files <  files.txt 
echo "${files[@]}"
for FILE in ${files[@]}; do

    bamtofastq-1.3.2 --nthreads 40 $FILE $FILE.folder
    cellranger count --id=sample_$FILE \
    --transcriptome=refdata-gex-GRCh38-2020-A \
    --fastqs=$FILE.folder/*/;
done
```

files.txt

```
scRNA_sorted_25183_Relapse_1_bam
scRNA_sorted_27522_Primary_bam
```

Error:

```
error: Invalid value for '--fastqs <PATH>...': No such file or directory: 'scRNA_sorted_25183_Relapse_1_bam.folder/*/'
```

Comment: The error message means that there are no non-hidden entries in the directory `scRNA_sorted_25183_Relapse_1_bam.folder`.  BTW, you better use quotes: `for FILE in "${files[@]}"; do`, just in case that one day, there are spaces in the file names.

Comment: For correct handling of spaces, quotes need to be added for _all_ variables, i.e. not only for `${files[@]}`, but also for all mentions of `$FILE`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that the wildcard in

```
--fastqs=$FILE.folder/*/
```

won't be expanded by the shell, i.e. `cellranger` receives the argument with the `*` as is.

Try it without the `=`, i.e.:

```
cellranger count --id=sample_$FILE \
--transcriptome=refdata-gex-GRCh38-2020-A \
--fastqs $FILE.folder/*/
```

Now, `cellranger` should receive the argument with the `*` expanded to the subfolder. I'm assuming here that there is only *one* subfolder - for multiple subfolders, additional code would be required as `--fastqs` expects a comma-separated list in that case.

---

As a side note, to handle files with spaces correctly, you would need to add a few quotes (this is generally a good idea when writing Bash scripts):

```
#!/bin/bash
mapfile -s 1 -t files < files.txt
echo "${files[@]}"
for FILE in "${files[@]}"; do
    bamtofastq-1.3.2 --nthreads 40 "$FILE" "$FILE.folder"
    cellranger count --id="sample_$FILE" \
    --transcriptome=refdata-gex-GRCh38-2020-A \
    --fastqs "$FILE.folder"/*/
done
```

Comment: I understand your point, but shouldn't be the error message in this case complain about a missing `--fastqs=scRNA_sorted_25183_Relapse_1_bam.folder/*/`?

Comment: No. `scRNA_sorted_25183_Relapse_1_bam.folder/*/` is being passed as the parameter for `--fastqs` to `cellranger`. But the `*` won't get expanded by the shell when using the `--param=arg` syntax.

Comment: In your solution, the expansion happens by the shell. Assuming that we have under `folder` two entries, A and B. This would lead to the command line `... --fastqs scRNA_sorted_25183_Relapse_1_bam.folder/A/ scRNA_sorted_25183_Relapse_1_bam.folder/B/ `. Wouldn't the appearance of the extra argument be a problem for _cellranger_?

Comment: Yes, I'm assuming here that `cellranger` is unable to handle wildcards by itself (its documentation does not mention wildcards), thus the shell needs to perform the expansion. Also, the OP states there is _a subfolder_, not multiple ones, thus this should work fine. Multiple folders would pose a problem as `cellranger` expects a comma-separated list in that case.